# Nothing named nw:clustering-coefficient has been defined

Tags: netlogo

I have included the extension [nw] at the beginning of the netlogo programme. But when I use "nw:clustering-coefficient", the error "Nothing named nw:clustering-coefficient has been defined" jumps out.

Answer (score 3):

This error might mean that you are using an older release candidate of the NW extension. The `nw:clustering-coefficient` has been added right before the release of NetLogo 5.1.0.

I would suggest making sure that you are using [NetLogo 5.1.0](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/5.1.0/) and the version of the extension that comes bundled with it.

You can see which version of NetLogo you are using in the **Help** / **About ...** menu. And the `nw:version` primitive will return the current version of the NW extension (which as of NetLogo 5.1.0 still shows `"1.0.0-RC4"`).

Comment: I have installed NetLogo 5.1.0. I also downloaded the newest version of NW extension (an file named "NW-Extension-master" after unzipped) and put it in the folder where the NetLogo programme is -- and delete the older version "nw" file at the same time. However when I run the "nw:version" code in the programme, it still prints out "1.0.0-RC3" not "1.0.0-RC4". Is there any problem with the way I install the NW extension please?

Comment: It has already changed to "1.0.0-RC4". I need to restart NetLogo... Thanks anyway!